# Strange output from custom string object

Tags: c

I'm working on the second half of a program for class and the objective of the program is simple, but I can't figure out what's causing this output for my program. Basically, we have to read a file, using a function we wrote for the string header. We should then print out all the four-letter words in that file, obviously ignoring punctuation and whitespace. I've got the logic for that down, but what I can't figure out is why, even though I check to see if the length of the string is 4 before printing it, I sometimes get output that's clearly longer than 4. Here is input text from the file I'm using.

```
This is a test of the program which will only print out the four letter words in this file. Let's see if it works!
```

And this is the output I'm getting...

```
This
test
willham
onlyham
fourtam
thissrm
filesrm
```

Here is the main program: http://pastebin.com/xviETPFm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "mystring.h"

int fTerminate(char ch, int * pbDiscardChar);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    MYSTRING str;
    FILE * in;

    if((str = mystring_init_default()) == MYSTRING_STATUS_ERROR) {
        printf("Error initializing MYSTRING object.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((in = fopen("book.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file \"book.txt\". Does the file exist?\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(mystring_input(str, in, 1, fTerminate) != MYSTRING_STATUS_ERROR) {
        if(mystring_size(str) == 4) {
            mystring_output(str, stdout);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    mystring_destroy(&str);

    return 0;
}

int fTerminate(char ch, int * pbDiscardChar) {
    // Terminate on whitespace characters or non-alpha characters.
    return (*pbDiscardChar = ((isspace(ch) || (isalpha(ch) == 0))?1:0));
}
```

And just in case you need it, here is the input function: http://pastebin.com/vD71hGEt

```
MyString_Status mystring_input(MYSTRING hString,
                               FILE * hFile,
                               int bIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace,
                               int (*fTerminate)(char ch, int * pbDiscardChar)) {
    char ch = '\0';
    int eofCheck = 0;
    int t, discard;

    mystring_truncate(hString, 0);

    if(hFile == NULL) return MYSTRING_STATUS_ERROR;
    eofCheck = fscanf(hFile, "%c", &ch);

    // If bIgnoreWhiteSpace is true, gobble leading whitespace.
    if(bIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace) {
        while(isspace(ch)) {
            eofCheck = fscanf(hFile, "%c", &ch);
            if(eofCheck == EOF) return MYSTRING_STATUS_ERROR;
        }
    }

    // Add all valid characters to the string, overwriting the old string.
    while(eofCheck != EOF) {
        t = fTerminate(ch, &discard);
        if(discard == 0) mystring_push(hString, ch);
        if(t) return MYSTRING_STATUS_SUCCESS;
        eofCheck = fscanf(hFile, "%c", &ch);
    }

    if(eofCheck == EOF) return MYSTRING_STATUS_ERROR;

    return MYSTRING_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

It clearly works for the first two strings, so what happened with the rest of them? Does my computer just like ham?

Comment: You're forgetting to null terminate your strings.

Comment: No, I'm not. I've been using this header for several other projects and it doesn't give me any similar problems.

Comment: Please, try to keep all relevant info in your question, not on an external site. Won't matter too much this time, as it should be deleted fast for having no content...

Comment: You can change the condition in the `fTerminate()` to `return (*pbDiscardChar = !isalpha(ch));`, though it is not clear why you need to echo the result of the condition in the return status _and_ the pointer argument (one should be sufficient, and the return value is better than the pointer argument).  The problem is almost certainly not in the code you show us.

Comment: Well your string is clearly getting the overflow from previous read words. It reads the first 6 words, gets to program and now the word is program. After that it reads which and your word is whicham. Next word is willham and each time you you read a word longer than 4 letters it will update the letters after the 4th and next time you read a 4 letter word it will print it with the extra letters from before. Null terminate your strings as @JonathanLeffler says.

Comment: The input function truncates the string to a size of 0 before reading anything in. It should be empty before anything is added, so no, it shouldn't retain anything from a previous string.

Comment: How does it truncate it? By the looks of the method signature it truncates a string that you send to it and the string you use to send to it.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I reverted to a previous version of the header's implementation before I came across this error, so it should give the same output as my original post, but now, it's just giving me this... "i,o,i,i,i". I even added checks in the functions that modify the string to add a null-terminator if there isn't one.

Comment: Does `mystring_push(hString, ch)` ensure the string is null terminated?  Does `mystring_output(str, stdout)` ensure it only outputs the characters pushed since the last truncate? It seems likely that one of those two is at fault.  But since we can't see your code, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Truncate realloc's the memory of the character array in the object to the new size. Since I specified 0, then it should be an empty string again.

Comment: Nope; `realloc()` doesn't zero the memory.  It just gives ... well, since you specified 0, you might get back a null pointer, or you might get a pointer to space you cannot legitimately write to.  It's always hard to find bugs when you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: It adds 1 to the length specified, so giving it 0 makes the new size 1. Then, it sets the character at the position (size - 1) to '\0'. So in other words, when you specify 0, it sets position 0 to '\0' since the new length of it will actually be 1.

Comment: You only call truncate at the start though. What does push do? Does it also realloc?

Comment: OK; I take your word for it, but only because you won't show the code that is (probably) defective.  If you want the actual answer to your problem, show us the code for the `mystring.h` header and the code for the `mystring_push()` and `mystring_truncate()` and `mystring_output()` functions.

Comment: I've decided not to include the NULL terminator in the character array in the object, because it interferes with some of the other functions. Instead, I want to add it to the output when the output function is called, but I can't think of a way to do that. It just calls fprintf() with the character array from the object. Is there a way I can include a NULL terminator at the end without modifying the actual array?

Comment: `printf("%s", ...)` prints until it finds a null character, and you can see that the longer words are bleeding into all the items (`....ham` has the "h" from "which" and "am" from "program"). You either need a null terminator or manually handle the output as a series of characters.

Comment: I like to think my computer just likes ham.

Anyway, I changed the program to add the null terminator when it outputs, and to just store the characters in sequence as a vector. I think that's how it was supposed to be originally, anyway.